# ios7 show status bar and change view bounds

Tags: view, statusbar, ios7

ok I know many people asked this question,
but mine is different from their situations.
many asked to hide the bar and they find the way,
my app, wanna launch without bar, and shows bar when loaded,
what I did is set Status bar is initially hidden to YES,
and in

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

works good on iOS6, view bounds 320*460
on iOS7, bounds of my view controller.view becomes 320*480, which under the status bar,

people say to change the origin.y of window and I tried, it leaves a 20px gap, but of course the status bar is clipped out,

I tried

- self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
- self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
  not working,

and many other ways, not working too.

anyone helps, pls dont downvote me, many people like me want the answer.

EDITING:
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; only works when you use a navigation bar by system,self.view became 416px, reduces 64, but if   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; you sill got a 480 px view....
so bad design .....